# INTELLIJ IDEA Build Output Error : Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.String'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intellij-idea, ide

I recently installed Intellj Idea Community Edition for learning Kotlin:
since I'm a Beginner I write some basic code which is as follows:

```
 fun main() {
        val x = readln().toString();
    
        println(x);
    }
```

I don't know if there are some spelling mistakes, and yeah I hit the run button to let the build process start
during the compilation, the build output showed this message:

> **Kotlin: Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.String'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies**[enter image description here]

This is my project Structure modules snapshot:

[image]

and this is my project libraries:
[image]
and my project setting :
[image]

I'm expecting to get this problem solved
thanks in advance

Comment: Try following this tutorial to create a new Kotlin project in IDEA: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/get-started-with-kotlin.html. In the 'New Project' wizard, make sure to check the box next to "Add sample code" to have a file with a sample 'Hello World' application created for you.

Comment: Which version of IDEA is this?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-233.13135.103, built on December 20, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.9+7-b1087.9 amd64

Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I think you have set java development Kit for you project so that the IDE can access all of the classes and tools that are needed to run your project
correctly.

simply walk through these steps:
File > Project Structure > Project Setting > Project > SDK > Edit button > here you have to locate your JDK main folder